# Totally disconnected orbit spaces

Tags: general-topology, locally-compact-groups

Let $X$ be a totally disconnected $G$-space, where $G$ is a locally compact Hausdorff group. Is the orbit space X/G also totally disconnected?

The same question for locally compact, Hausdorff, totally disconnected topological group $G$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The orbit space is not necessarily disconnected. For a simple example, let $X$ be the
irrational reals, with the order topology and let $G$ be the rationals with the
discrete topology. $G$ is then locally compact, metrizable and totally disconnected, and it acts continuously on $X$ by the addition of real numbers.
It is easy to see though, that every orbit is dense in $X$, therefore the
orbit space is indiscrete.

Some additional notes:

- Any subgroup of $\text{Homeo}(X)$ with the discrete topology has all
  the required properties, including being totally disconnected.
- Adding the additional requirement that $G$ is not discrete makes no 
  difference, because you can e.g. multiply $X$ and $G$ by a
  disconnected local field and let that act on itself by addition. This
  produces essentially the same orbit space.
- Requiring that the group is totally disconnected makes no real difference
  anyway, since a continuous map into a totally disconnected space must be
  constant on on every connected subset of its domain. In this case that
  means that the action of the connected component of $G$ is always trivial.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If we also assume that the orbit space X/G is Hausdorff, can we conclude that X/G is totally disconnected?

Comment: I'm not sure. If you also add the condition that $X$ is compact Hausdorff, then it is zero-dimensional and the quotient map is closed as well as open. In that case $X/G$ is also zero-dimensional.

Comment: Maybe $X$ only has to be locally compact Hausdorff, since then the homeomorphisms of $X$ can be extended to homeomorphisms of its one point compactification which fix the added point.

Answer (score -1):

Well, let's see. To show that $X/G$ is totally disconnected, (by which I assume you mean that every point is open), we need to show that every $y \in X/G$ is open.

Now, the open sets in a quotient space are by definition, the images under the projection map of the open sets of $X$. So, a set $S$ is open, if it is $\pi(U)$ for some open set $U$ in $X$ where $\pi: X \rightarrow X/G$ is the projection.

However, if $X$ is totally disconnected, then every subset of $X$ is open. Hence, 
$$y = \pi(\pi^{-1}(y))$$
is open and thus $X/G$ is totally disconnected.

This is actually an example of the more general fact that the images of totally disconnected spaces under open maps are totally disconnected.

Comment: Every point is open means space is discrete. Totally disconnected spaces are not necessarily discrete. A topological space X is totally disconnected if the connected components in X are the one-point sets.

Comment: Is $X$ not necessarily locally path connected? In locally path connected spaces connected components are open. I think that was in my assumption sorry.

Comment: X is not necessarily locally path connected. At least, I don't know the reason for it.